# Different PDF output In IE Vs FF using TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

In our webapplication we create a PDF based on some XHTML code. For some test purposed I've added some static XHTML in A PHP variable and put that into TCPDF which create as follow a PDF from it. The strange thing is that the PDF which are created in Firefox is different then the PDF I created in Internet Explorer. Same URL / Same code / Same content for the PDF.

I've writed the PDF to the filesystem for the tests and look the PDF's with Adobe reader.

How is this possible? TCPDF is browser independent I think.

Comment: Stange. TCPDF does not depend on browser. But possibly your web app generate different output depending on browser? Or maybe you are taking some part of HTML from browser, for instance, using `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code, add it in the PHP code section. Also check the XHTML content works same in both IE and FF. Just view the content in browser before creating the PDF.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf')
```